# set the number of reducers does not work

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I am using Hadoop streaming with -io typedbytes and set mapred.reduce.tasks=2, but I finally got only one output file. And if I set mapred.reduce.tasks=0, then I got many output files. I am very confused.

SO my question is:
     **How to make mapred.reduce.tasks = num (num >1) config valid when I using -io typedbytes in streaming?**

*PS: my mapper's output is (key:string of python, value:array of numpy) .*
And my .sh file:
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 \
-fs local \
-jt local \
-io typedbytes \
-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat \
-input FFT_SequenceFile \
-output pinvoutput \
-mapper 'pinvmap.py' \
-file pinvmap.py \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 \ -fs local \ -jt local
```

By checking values of `-fs` and `-jt` i came to know you are running it in `local` mode.
In `local` mode, **either zero or one reducer can run atmost**.
Because it uses local file system and a single JVM, there is no Hadoop daemons in this mode.
In `psuedo distributed` mode where all the daemons runs on the same machine, the property `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=n` will work and results `n` reducers.
So you should use `psuedo distributed` mode for working with multiple reducers.
Hope it helps!

Comment: BTW, if you have many output files when you use `mapred.reduce.tasks=0`, it's because there are no reducers and so you are looking to your mappers' output.

Comment: Thank you, Chowdary & ALSimon. It works all right now.